# Hello World no Android consumindo muita memória RAM

Tags: android, gerenciamento-de-memória

Estou fazendo uma aplicação e percebi que ela está consumindo muita memória RAM, aproximadamente 70MB. Tenho um botão que infla um layout extra com dados aleatórios e que ficam mudando dinamicamente que por conta disso faz aumentar a memória utilizada no Android.

Pesquisando a fundo percebi que o **Hello World** do Andorid já consome 13MB e ele só tem uma `activity` e um texto.

Minha pergunta é **como melhorar o uso da memória no código do aplicativo?**
Como faço para limpar a memória cache ou matar uma activity? (No meu app matar uma activity não resolve muito)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe uma Thread no grupo Android Brazil Dev (Google Groups) que fala sobre o gerenciamento de memória e reserva de memoria, vale a pena dar um lida.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/androidbrasil-dev/cFcEAI5LPIc

Edit:

Essa thread de discussão no Google Group traz uma informação muito importante onde existe um alocação de memória minima para cada tipo de device veja.

[image: Fonte: (http://source.android.com/compatibility/downloads.html]
Obs: Acho meio estranho aplicativos que utilzia xLarge com Screem Density de xxHdpi utilizar 256MB, para mim é muita memoria.

fonte: http://source.android.com/compatibility/downloads.html

Outra informação muito importante com o controle de imagens onde é orientando a diminuir a imagens utilizando o processo de thumbnail.

Segue os links bem interessantes sobre o gerenciamento de memoria no Android.

[Video Google IO 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk)

[Weak references](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/enicholas/archive/2006/05/understanding_w.html)

[Material como funciona o Garbage Colector](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/enicholas/archive/2006/05/understanding_w.html)

Comment: lá diz que o processamento de imagens aumenta a memoria reservada para  app, isso pode ocorrer com png também?

Comment: Qualquer tipo de imagem, por isso é altamente recomendado você diminuir o tamanho da imagem antes de carregar, tipo criar criar um thumbnail. Para isso procure por Bitmap.createScaledBitmap o processo é basicamente criar um arquivo reduzido tendo como base o arquivo original. Edit: Logico que criar o thumbnail somente para demostrar na galeria, mas tenha a opção do usuário visualizar o imagem no tamanho original.

Comment: Mesmo que este link seja uma boa sugestão, esta resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Por isso, e também porque é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui mesmo, seria melhor você responder com respostas mais completas. Você pode elaborar mais sua resposta? Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Respostas que apenas contêm links são boas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/705/respostas-que-apenas-contem-links-sao-boas)